# How to find something by text in xpath?

Tags: php, html, text, xpath, find

I've got a problem, I have this html source code:

```
<td class="specs_title">
Processortype
<a href="#" class="info-link">
<img src="x.jpg" title="" height="16" alt="" width="16" />
<span class="info-popup">
<span class="hd">Processortype</span>
<span class="bd">Text</span>
</span>
</a>
</td>
<td class="specs_descr">
Intel Core i3
</td>
<td class="specs_title">
Spec
<a href="#" class="info-link">
<img src="y.jpg" title="" height="16" alt="" width="16" />
<span class="info-popup">
<span class="hd">Processortype</span>
<span class="bd">Text</span>
</span>
</a>
</td>
<td class="specs_descr">
Other Spec
</td>
```

I have to get "Intel Core i3" out of this page by php and XPath and I wanted to do it by a query that searches the text Processortype and do something with that.
Is this even possible, if so HOW? 
Thanks for even replying!

Comment: "I wanted to do it by a query that searches the text Processortype" - Why do you need to use this text? Can't you just fetch the contents of `td` nodes with `@class='specs_descr'`?

Comment: Do you need _"Other Spec"_ as well (as the title before that contains `<span class="hd">Processortype</span>`), or _only_ the _"Intel Core i3"_, as it's in the bare `specs_title`?

Comment: The way it is, it needs to be working on more different pages and it varies from where in a list it is, so class can't do much, the only thing that stays the same is the text Processortype. And it's html parsing within php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$XML = '
<root>
    <td class="specs_title">
        Processortype
        <a href="#" class="info-link">
            <img src="x.jpg" title="" height="16" alt="" width="16" />
            <span class="info-popup">
                <span class="hd">Processortype</span>
                <span class="bd">Text</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="specs_descr">
        Intel Core i3
    </td>
    <td class="specs_title">
        Spec
        <a href="#" class="info-link">
            <img src="y.jpg" title="" height="16" alt="" width="16" />
            <span class="info-popup">
                <span class="hd">Processortype</span>
                <span class="bd">Text</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="specs_descr">
        Other Spec
    </td>
</root>';
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($XML);
var_dump(array_map('strval',$sxe->xpath("
    //td[@class='specs_title' and contains(.,'Processortype')]
    /following-sibling::td[@class='specs_descr'][1]")));
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(27) "
        Intel Core i3
    "
  [1] =>
  string(24) "
        Other Spec
    "
}
```

Comment: This was reaaaaly good! Very effective and precisely what I wanted to have!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be using [Symfony's DomCrawler component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<EOF
<td class="specs_title">
    Processortype
    <a href="#" class="info-link">
        <img src="x.jpg" title="" height="16" alt="" width="16" />
        <span class="info-popup">
            <span class="hd">Processortype</span>
            <span class="bd">Text</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
<td class="specs_descr">
    Intel Core i3
</td>
<td class="specs_title">
    Spec
    <a href="#" class="info-link">
        <img src="y.jpg" title="" height="16" alt="" width="16" />
        <span class="info-popup">
            <span class="hd">Processortype</span>
            <span class="bd">Text</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
<td class="specs_descr">
    Other Spec
</td>
EOF;

$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addContent($html);
$nodes = $crawler->filterXPath("//td[@class='specs_descr']");
echo $nodes->first()->text(); //This prints exactly "Intel Core i3"
```

Comment: @Wrikken Yeah, I read that. I'm not sure why it's needed for the template provided, as my answer provides the desired output. Anyway, your answer seems more complete.